# Task.WaitAny to accept Task<T> instead of Task [ ]

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, task-parallel-library, task

I have a collection of generic Tasks those are marked for execution. As and when a  task complete (using `Task.WaitAny`), I am adding it to an `ObservableCollection`.

But, the issue is at `Task.WaitAny(...)` line, which says **Co-variant array conversion from Task<MyType>[] to Task[] can cause run-time exception on write operation.**

I am fairly knowledgeable on what this exception means and why it complains at this stage.

**Question:** Is there any generic version of `Task.WaitAny()`, which can take `Task<T>` as parameter instead of `Task[]`.

Thanks in advance.

[image: code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a generic Task.WaitAll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044099/is-there-a-generic-task-waitall)

Comment: @chuex The answers to that questions are outdated. There is a better way now.

Comment: @Nair: Why are the tasks in an *observable collection* to begin with? Surely they aren't being data-bound...

Comment: @StephenCleary, This code is just a stripped version to demonstrate the issue. Now to answer your question, the result from individual task has to be bound to a control in WPF and intention is to have responsive UI.

Comment: @Nair: You can't bind to `Task<T>.Result` and have a responsive UI.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a generic `Task.WhenAny`

```
public static Task<Task<TResult>> WhenAny<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks);
public static Task<Task<TResult>> WhenAny<TResult>(params Task<TResult>[] tasks);
```

`await` it to get the completed task.

Comment: Appreciate your support. Sorry I am using .NET 4.

Comment: @Nair If you're using .NET 4 in VS 2012 or higher, you can get Microsoft.Bcl.Async package from nuget and use TaskEx.WhenAny.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Task.WhenAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194914(v=vs.110).aspx) which in your case will even simplify your code like this

```
var result = new ObservableCollection<LenderScoreCard>();
var parallelScoreList = parallelScore.ToList();
while (parallelScoreList.Count != 0)
{
    var completedTask = Task.WhenAny(parallelScoreList).Result;
    result.Add(completedTask.Result);
    parallelScoreList.Remove(completedTask);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your support. Sorry I am using .NET 4.

Comment: @Nair: Np, then just ignore the warning - `Task.WaitAny` does not modify the passed array anyway.